# Merge the tags Muhammad and Prophet Muhammad

Tags: discussion, tag

There are two tags [muhammad](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muhammad) and [prophetmuhammad](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prophetmuhammad) which are actually the same and should be merged.

Answer (score 0):

The two tags were already synonyms; I have completed the merge [muhammad](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/muhammad)->[prophetmuhammad](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prophetmuhammad).

Comment: I think it should be prophet-muhammad to have other tags like prophet-jesus, prophet-moses as well.